# Laravel 4: Failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm having problem in setting up Laravel 4. I'm having this error when opening the index page:

> file_put_contents(/Users/laravel/app/storage/meta/services.json) [function.file-put-contents]:
> failed to open stream: Permission denied.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The `storage` directory needs to be writable by the webserver user.

Comment: How do I do that? Will that be chmod?

Comment: I had to do 777 first. Then I reverted to 755 and it worked. I couldn't get 644 to work.

Comment: And bootstrap dir, in my case

Answer (score 52):

I think chmod -777 is a bad practice.

To solve permissions issue on Laravel, I've done this (with root user):

`cd app/`

`chown -R www-data:www-data storage`

`cd storage/`

`find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;`

And always in app/storage directory :

`chown your_user:user_group .gitignore cache/.gitignore logs/.gitignore meta/.gitignore sessions/.gitignore views/.gitignore`

Now, exit the root user, and it's ok.

EDIT : this was for Laravel4. This doesn't works for Laravel5 because of a different structure.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful. Just for more info, in OSX 10.9, the default user and group that the apache (apache that was shipped with OSX) is _www and _www so I did chown -R _www:_www storage/

Comment: +1 Only changes for Laravel 5 are that you don't do `cd app` first and the last command should be `chown vagrant:www-data .gitignore framework/cache/.gitignore logs/.gitignore app/.gitignore framework/sessions/.gitignore framework/views/.gitignore`

Comment: Probably, it would be easier to use `chmod` instead of `find`: `chmod -R  ug=rwX,o=r app/storage`

Answer (score 15):

It's better that you do not change the permissions, you should just change the `owner:group` of the storage folder to that of the `owner:group` of apache by using `chown`, this is more complicated but is more secure and you'll get used to this soon, you can find this in the **httpd.conf**

**MAMP:**

```
/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf
```

**XAMMP:**

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf
```

Open the httpd.conf with your preferred editor then search for `User/Group`. After searching you will see these lines below that highlighted line you searched:

```
User someuser
Group somegroup
```

Once you already know the User and Group, cd to your laravel directory then, do the `chown`:

```
chown -R someuser:somegroup app/storage
```

P.S:
If you get permission something error upon doing `chown`, try this:

```
sudo chown -R someuser:somegroup app/storage
```

It will then ask for your password so input it then done.

Comment: In debian 7 you should change the user/group in /etc/apache2/envvars and then change the ownership of /var/lock/apache2. I suppose that in other debian based linux should be similar.

Answer (score 5):

Just ran into this problem on centos 7. The blocker wasn't folder permissions, rather it was selinux policy blocking nginx/php to access /var/www. So, if the above doesn't work, try disabling selinux as a test to see if you can re-run composer without any permission issues.

Comment: This took me almost an entire day to figure out.  [Here's a link to more information on this program](http://www.crypt.gen.nz/selinux/disable_selinux.html) as well as how to disable it.

For quick reference the command is:
`setenforce 0`

Comment: You should NOT disable selinux. You can solve your problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27377624/2570054

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache on Ubuntu, storage and bootstrap/cache folders need to be writable by web server user.

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

This will allow write permissions to these folders for web server users.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error was thrown:

> fopen(php://stdout): failed to open stream: operation failed

i am using a virtual host in Wamp.
therefor i added this line to my `<VirtualHost>` -> `<Directory>` block in `httpd-vhosts.conf` file:

```
Require all granted
```

and my block is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName laravel
    DocumentRoot d:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "d:/wamp/www/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

then problem solved!