# chmod equivalent for windows

Tags: google-app-engine, laravel, chmod

I am deploying a laravel app in GAE. I am getting the following problem:

> file_put_contents(/base/data/home/apps/s~national-test/1.375571546917553599/app/storage/meta/services.json):
>   failed to open stream: Read-only file system

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020513/laravel-4-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied/22192814#22192814) I found a solution, but this works for linux and I am using windows 8. Which is equivalent chmod -R 755 app/storage for windows?
I really need some help

Comment: _“Read-only file system”_ – that sound like a permission problem to you …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having problems only with meta/services.json, just delete it and Laravel will recreate it.

But you can use git itself to set permissions:

```
git update-index --chmod=775 <file or dir>
```

Comment: the problem is that it doesn't exists in meta folder

Comment: I had everything ok, till i run composer update. After this my app at GAE shows this error.

Comment: I solved this way :CACLS  -R 755 app/storage (as admin). Thank you very much :)

Comment: The only problem that I have now is that i cant run it localy( Indeed this is another question) But it shows me this error: PHP Startup: apc_fcntl_create: could not open C:\Windows\.apc.a06812