# "laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have setup Laravel homestead on a local OSX machine, everything seemed to be going smoothly until I tried to open example.app:8000 and got this error:

```
Error in exception handler: The stream or file "/home/vagrant/Code/example/app/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Protocol error in /home/vagrant/Code/example/bootstrap/compiled.php:8671
```

I followed the Laravel docs as well as a Laracast about setting up homestead, so I am not sure what would be causing this. I can see that `/home/vagrant/Code/example/app/storage/logs/laravel.log` doesn't exist, but I assume that is something that should be created automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run one of the following:

- `sudo chmod -R 644 app/storage`
- `sudo chmod -R 755 app/storage`

Comment: `sudo chmod -R 644 app/storage` took care of the error but now I just see a blank white page. When I try to edit `app/routes.php` I get a permission denied error. Did I mess up permissions for this whole thing somehow?

Comment: For More information please you reffere : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411520/error-laravel-log-could-not-be-opened or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020513/laravel-4-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied

Comment: @ChiragShah it's a bit irresponsible to provide commands like this (especially involving permissions) with no explanation, and then when his system breaks you simply point him to other answers. Lazy.

Answer (score 78):

All files and folders under `app/storage` should be *writable* by you and group *www-data* (the webserver).

> Error in exception handler: The stream or file "laravel/app/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:77

If you get this error (or a similar error) in the browser when accessing your site, then the group `www-data` can't write to `app/storage`. If you get this error when you execute certain `php artisan` commands, then you (the user) can't write to `app/storage`. Therefore both you and the www-data group must have write permission.

---

To ensure the files and folders have the correct permissions:

1. Go to the root of your Laravel installation (where `composer.json` and `artisan` live).
2. Change the owning user and group, where `yourusername` is your username:

   ```
   sudo chown -R yourusername:www-data app/storage
   ```

   This recursively (`-R`) sets the user:group owners to `yourusername:www-data` in all files and folders from `app/storage` onward.
3. Add the write permission for both you and the `www-data` group:

   ```
   sudo chmod -R ug+w app/storage
   ```

   This recursively (`-R`) adds (`+`) the write flag (`w`) to the user (`u`) and group (`g`) that own the files and folders from `app/storage` onward.
4. Additionally, some suggest you may need to flush the application cache.

   ```
   php artisan cache:clear
   ```
5. Finally, you may want to regenerate Composer's autoload files.

   ```
   composer dump-autoload
   ```

Comment: This is the best option, but giving 777 to storage, it work on that particular date but when new error is generate on other day, the log is create by www-data, so again permission error is thrown.
But @Virtlink, is this safe to give write permission to www-data on production server also? Our code will be safe with this??

Comment: I keep getting an illegal group name error when trying to change the owning users / group

Comment: For my case the  issue was SELinux. "sudo setenforce 0" solved it.

Comment: We use a cPanel environment. Our web requests aren't run by www-data, they are run by the active user or the `nobody` user. So `chgrp www-data` doesn't work.

Comment: Is this solutions specific to linux? On Mac I get `chown: www-data: illegal group name`

Comment: thanks for the great explanation but this isnt any command ```php artisan dump-autoload```

Comment: The `php artisan dump-autoload` command seems to have been removed. Everything else works but that command is no longer in the artisan manual.

Comment: One thing to add, make sure your `storage/logs/laravel.log` file is created before applying these changes. In my case that file was created after and therefore was not under the `www-data` group and resulted in the same errors.

Answer (score 4):

As for me I had changed my storage permission with `chmod -R 777 storage` and it's work well.

However, setting 777 permissions is incredibly dangerous and should not be done on any server other than your local machine.

I had checked for this configuration at [here](http://laravel.com/docs/installation#configuration).

Comment: Again and again people keep telling that `777` is the answer to all but no and no and again no. Linux system did not built this kind of permission configuration for nothing. 777 does not mean jackpot, It just means that you are giving any user all permission to the files.  Go to this brilliant answer written by marco https://askubuntu.com/a/20110/700927 and you will know what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

If changing the file permissions as described in the other answers didn't work and you're using CentOS 7 or RHEL then the issue may be a security program called selinux.  I struggled with all kinds of permissions and groups before noticing user3670777 answer to [Laravel 4: Failed to open stream: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020513/laravel-4-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied/26265384#comment42502087_26265384)

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

If All Above suggestions not working disable your selinux and try again

Answer (score -6):

im pretty new on laravel. May be I could not explain it in depth but that command fixed my problem.

```
chmod -R 777 storage/
```

Comment: As pointed out in other comments, this is a dangerous solution. A bit like taking the front door off your house so the postman can deliver a parcel.