# Permissions Issue with Laravel on CentOS

Tags: linux, apache, laravel, permissions, centos

I've cloned a laravel repo to my CentOS 7 box. When I try to run it, I get a 500 error with nothing displayed.

So I check out `/var/log/httpd/error_log` and I see that I've got some permissions errors:

```
[Mon May 16 11:39:32.996441 2016] [:error] [pid 2434] [client 104.156.67.195:39136] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/var/www/html/MYSITE/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/MYSITE/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php:13701
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/MYSITE/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(13635): Monolog\\Handler\\StreamHandler->write(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/MYSITE/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(13396): Monolog\\Handler\\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/MYSITE/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(13494): Monolog\\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException), Array)
#3 /var/www/html/MYSITE/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(13189): Monolog\\Logger->error(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException), Array)
#4 /var/www/html/MYSITE/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(13160): Illuminate\\Log\\Writer->writeLog('error', Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException), Array)
# in /var/www/html/MYSITE/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php on line 13701
```

I have done the following to try to overcome the issues:

```
chmod -R 775 storage
chmod -R 775 vendor
chown -R apache:apache storage
```

So it now shows as so:

```
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 apache apache 2156 May 16 11:41 storage/logs/laravel.log
```

But that didn't work.

Interestingly enough, I mis-typed some `artisan` commands earlier and those seemed to add logs to the logfile...

#### I already read/tried:

- [“laravel.log” could not be opened: failed to open stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24055227/1007638)
- [Error: laravel.log could not be opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411520/error-laravel-log-could-not-be-opened)
- [log file permission problem](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/log-file-permission-problem)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

## Turns out the issue is with `selinux`

[I found this answer](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel5-gives-blank-page-with-500-status-code-on-apache-fedora22/replies/98874), which solved my problem.

> Prove this is the problem by turning off `selinux` with the command
>
> ```
> setenforce 0
> ```
>
> This should allow writing, but you've turned off added security
>   server-wide. That's bad. Turn SELinux back
>
> ```
> setenforce 1
> ```
>
> Then finally use SELinux to allow writing of the file by using this
>   command
>
> ```
> chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t storage
> ```
>
> And you're off!

Comment: I have tried chmod, I have tried chown, I have checked ACL, they all not work... you saved me a lot of time...thanks

Comment: I wasted a lot of time on this problem. This was the solution that got me moving again.

Comment: failed to get security context of `logs': Operation not supported

Comment: I want to acknowledge that, this is best answer when I deploy php project such as **laravel** website on `CentOS`, `selinux` is default firewall in `RHEL CentOS` system, Thank you

Comment: spent like 2 hours on this problem... thx for the solution...

Comment: `chcon` is temporary solution. Use `semanage` to set directory context permanently. `chcon` set context will be restored to default on reboot

Comment: This is like 4 years old and still gets a lot of attention. I'm gonna revisit this before end of year with an updated answer

Comment: I have spent almost 7 hours & reset my server changed nginx to apache. Also i have changed selinux in config file but didn't worked.

Thank you so much your solution worked for me.  Many Thanks..

Answer (score 10):

I need to make more adjustments for SELinux than just for `storage`.  Especially the `config` dir can get you this issue on Laravel bootstrapping.

If you `sudo setenforce permissive` and it works, then turn it back `sudo setenforce enforcing` then follow below.

**SELinux laravel setup:**

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/www/site/laravel/storage(/.*)?"
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/www/site/laravel/bootstrap/cache(/.*)?"
```

You may not need the following one for `config`, but i did.  It may be safest not to run this one unless you need to:

`sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/www/site/laravel/config(/.*)?"`

Then Reset after your dir adjustments have been made:

`restorecon -Rv /var/www/site/`

Comment: This is the better way to do it than chcon, which will get reset if anyone ever calls restorecon or if the filesystem is relabelled. I agree with storage and bootstrap/cache. However, you _really_ shouldn't make the config folder writable by the web server. Stock Laravel certainly does not need the config folder to be writable.

Comment: I think for me, if i recall correctly, the reason i wrote this post, was because of that very dir.   That was my only issue `config`.  So, i dont recall my setup on that, sorry.  I would say dont do config, unless you need to.

Comment: this answer should be correct answer, remember `chcon` only for temporary. `semanage` for permanently

Answer (score 5):

try these worked for me ...

```
sudo find ./storage -type f -exec chmod 666 {} \;
sudo find ./storage -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

Comment: 777 permission is a security risk !

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was another unix user so this one worked:

```
chown -R php-fpm:php-fpm storage
```

Answer (score 1):

cd [laravelfolder]

```
chmod 777 storage -R

sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t storage -R

chmod 777 bootstrap

sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t bootstrap -R
```

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS 7 I had similar permissions issue. The solution which works for me is:

Add user centos to group apache

Add user apache to group centos

Restart httpd

The final line is vital as otherwise user apache will not be aware it is now also in group centos!

Same as user apache logging out and back in again.

Comment: This would be way too permissive for any production server

Answer (score 0):

I spent several hours looking for an easy solution in vain. I had to learn how SELinux works. [This was quite helpful](https://opensource.com/article/18/7/sysadmin-guide-selinux)

Follow these steps to give `php-fpm(httpd)` the proper access rights to serve your laravel application on CentOS.

For some reason, I couldn't do this at the `storage/` and `bootstrap/cache/` level so I had to go down into the specific folders

0 (a) `sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/var/www/your_app(/.*)?"`

0 (b) `restorecon -Rv /var/www/your_app`

1 (a). `sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/your_app/storage/framework/views'`

1(b). `sudo restorecon -v /var/www/your_app/storage/framework/views'`

2 (a). `sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/your_app/storage/framework/cache'`

2 (b). `sudo restorecon -v /var/www/your_app/storage/framework/cache'`

3 (a). `sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/your_app/storage/framework/sessions'`

3 (b). `sudo restorecon -v /var/www/your_app/storage/framework/sessions'`

4 (a). `sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/your_app/bootstrap/cache/data'`

4 (b). `sudo restorecon -v /var/www/your_app/bootstrap/cache/data'`

5 (a) `sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_log_t "/var/www/your_app/storage/logs"`

5 (b) `sudo restorecon -v /var/www/your_app/storage/logs'`