# Laravel 5.4 - 500 error after install

Tags: apache, laravel, permissions, centos, selinux

Yesterday I've installed a fresh CentOS 7 VM with Apache, MySQL and PHP 7.0.17.

After that, I installed composer and all other required php-packages.

Then I followed this guide to install Firefly-iii : https://firefly-iii.github.io/using-installing.html.

So far so good. The database is migrated and seeded from the php artisan migrate command.

Now the problem, when I try to access the application from the browser, a 500 error appears. No log rules, nothing.

Alright, this might be an permissions problem. I have changed the owner to apache:apache, no result. Set the storage and bootstrap/cache folder to 777 no result.

Alright... What now. Ah, maybe the user or usergroup is incorrect. I've copied my public/index.php and built in some try catch statement (still no log).

When I open the application in the browser finally some result is returned.

This try/catch:

```
try {
        $response = $kernel->handle(
            $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
        );
} catch (Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        echo '<br/>';
        echo 'User: '.exec('whoami');
        echo '<br/>';
        echo 'Group: '.exec('groups');
        echo '<br/>';
}
```

returns the following result:

```
The stream or file "/var/www/html/application-folder/storage/logs/application-name-2017-04-06.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied
User: apache
Group: apache
```

After this message I've created the /var/www/html/application-folder/storage/logs/application-name-2017-04-06.log file and changed the permissions to 777.

Here is a little piece of my bash history :

```
[user@16 logs]$ sudo chmod 777 firefly-iii-2017-04-06.log
[sudo] password for user:
[user@16 logs]$ ls -l
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 apache apache 5 Apr  6 14:18 firefly-iii-2017-04-06.log
[user@16 logs]$ chmod 777 firefly-iii-2017-04-06.log
chmod: changing permissions of ‘firefly-iii-2017-04-06.log’: Operation not permitted
```

This error messages is still returning and at this moment I've no idea what else I can try to fix this problem.

Does anyone knows a solution or has anybody else expecting this strange behavior?

Please help me, I am completely stuck at this moment and don't know what to do now and how I can solve this problem.

Comment: You have to set permissions to all **storage** folder

Comment: Yeah, I know I have to set the permissions for the whole storage folder. I also set the whole project folder to 777. But it all doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Maybe you're setting permissions in wrong way... Please check permissions of file manually.

Comment: I've tried to set the permissions with chmod 777, chmod a+rw, setfacl and changed user to apache with chown apache:apache. I really don't know an other way of settings permissions.

Comment: Did you do this with **-r** parameter?

Comment: Yes, i've used the -r parameter.

Answer (score 1):

After a little bit of search yesterday I've found this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37258323/1805919

I've tried it on my own server, and at this moment the application is accessible trough the browser.

> Prove this is the problem by turning off `selinux` with the command
>
> ```
> setenforce 0
> ```
>
> This should allow writing, but you've turned off added security
>   server-wide. That's bad. Turn SELinux back
>
> ```
> setenforce 1
> ```
>
> Then finally use SELinux to allow writing of the file by using this
>   command
>
> ```
> chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t storage
> ```
>
> And you're off!

Answer (score 0):

First of all your server has to be in owner group of application path.

Second you have to set permissions to **storage** folder. Here is an example how to set permissions on *nix systems:

```
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

Comment: Cleared the cache with `php artisan cache:clear` , but didn't help

Comment: How about clear all cache? 
`php artisan route:clear && php artisan cache:clear && php artisan config:clear && php artisan view:clear`

Comment: `php artisan route:clear && php artisan cache:clear && php artisan config:clear && php artisan view:clear`
`Route cache cleared!`
`Cache cleared successfully.`
`Configuration cache cleared!`
`Compiled views cleared!`


Still same error message

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not.

Comment: @Roy please check file permissions manually. Maybe it's just not set

Comment: I have checked all files by hand, even with the setfacl command. All files are writable by apache user.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a new application key? Have you also ran your migrations and created the database for the application?

Comment: I have tried re-installing the application 3 times with `composer create-project grumpydictator/firefly-iii --no-dev --prefer-dist`

Comment: Server restart?

Comment: Tried server restart, apache restart, changed .conf file and after that a restart. Nothing seems to help.

Comment: Did you run the migrations and create the database for the application?

Comment: All the migrations are runned, also the seed of the database. I've checked the database by hand, and there is data in it.