# CentOS, Nginx: 403 Forbidden in Laravel's folder

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I use `laravel new test` to establish the Laravel project and move all directories into `/usr/share/nginx/html/`, the default root directory of Nginx. 
In order to check if the config of nginx is correct, I simply the config, trun on `autoindex`, and put index,html into `/usr/share/nginx/html/test/public/`, the location of `index.php` of laravel.

**defaul.conf** of nginx

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/test;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        autoindex on;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

When I access the index.html by `localhost/public/`, nginx returns me 403. I copy index.html into a new folder named `/usr/share/nginx/html/test/public_b`, and try to access the new index.html by `localhost/public_b/`. Nginx returns me the correct content! It is like a miracle. The stats of my directories as the follows.

```
$ll /usr/share/html/test
total 432
drwxrwxr-x.  6 nginx nginx     84 Feb 26 15:39 app
-rw-rw-r--.  1 nginx nginx   1686 Feb 26 15:39 artisan
drwxrwxr-x.  3 nginx nginx     34 Feb 26 15:39 bootstrap
-rw-rw-r--.  1 nginx nginx   1512 Feb 26 15:39 composer.json
-rw-rw-r--.  1 nginx nginx 145089 Feb 26 15:39 composer.lock
drwxrwxr-x.  2 nginx nginx    247 Feb 26 15:39 config
drwxrwxr-x.  5 nginx nginx     72 Feb 26 15:39 database
-rwxrwxr-x.  1 nginx nginx     13 Feb 26 17:46 index.html
-rw-rw-r--.  1 nginx nginx   1150 Feb 26 15:39 package.json
-rw-rw-r--.  1 nginx nginx   1040 Feb 26 15:39 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root  root     116 Feb 26 18:05 public
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root      24 Feb 26 17:50 public_c
drwxrwxr-x.  5 nginx nginx     45 Feb 26 15:39 resources
drwxrwxr-x.  2 nginx nginx     75 Feb 26 16:50 routes
-rw-rw-r--.  1 nginx nginx    563 Feb 26 15:39 server.php
drwxr-xr-x.  5 nginx nginx     46 Feb 26 15:39 storage
drwxrwxr-x.  4 nginx nginx     83 Feb 26 15:39 tests
drwxrwxr-x. 37 nginx nginx   4096 Feb 26 15:40 vendor
-rw-rw-r--.  1 nginx nginx    549 Feb 26 15:39 webpack.mix.js
-rw-rw-r--.  1 nginx nginx 258941 Feb 26 15:39 yarn.lock
```

---

```
$ ll /usr/share/nginx/html/test/public
total 12
drwxrwxr-x. 2 nginx nginx   21 Feb 26 15:39 css
-rw-rw-r--. 1 nginx nginx    0 Feb 26 15:39 favicon.ico
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root  root    13 Feb 26 17:49 index.html
-rw-rw-r--. 1 nginx nginx 1823 Feb 26 15:39 index.php
drwxrwxr-x. 2 nginx nginx   20 Feb 26 15:39 js
-rw-rw-r--. 1 nginx nginx   24 Feb 26 15:39 robots.txt
```

---

```
$ ll /usr/share/nginx/html/test/public_c/
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 13 Feb 26 17:50 index.html
```

I have read a lot of relative questions and pages, but nothing help against this problem. **What is wrong in my actions or settings?**

---

**Update**

Thanks @Adam Kozlowski. I tried `chmod 777 public -R` and changing owner to both of root and nginx, but the problem was not solved.

Comment: Have you config the `php-fpm`?

Comment: `nginx` need it to run `php`. I'm pretty sure, if you add `index.html` in `/usr/share/nginx/html/test/public/` it would display something, instead of `403`.

Comment: @DharmaSaputra I have configured the `php-fpm`. But I think I have cut off the connection between `nginx` and `php-fpm` by `nginx`'s configuration.

Comment: I expect that `nginx` will display the content of the HTML I created, too. But nginx displays 403.

Comment: @DharmaSaputra Thnx a lot... It saved me !! adding index.html works like charms !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem: SELinux blocked Nginx to access the folders.

```
$ ls /usr/share/nginx/html/test/ -Z
drwxr-xr-x. root  root  unconfined_u:object_r:config_home_t:s0 public
drwxr-xr-x. root  root  unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 public_c
```

Only the files with the tag, `httpd_sys_content_t`, can be accessed by HTTP.

**Command:**

`chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /usr/share/nginx/html/test`

And I also need to add `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` to `/usr/share/nginx/html/test/storage` to let Laravel work.

**Command:**

`chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t/usr/share/nginx/html/test/storage`

Referring [Permissions Issue with Laravel on CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257975/permissions-issue-with-laravel-on-centos)

Answer (score 0):

Set proper permission for directory, as a root user:

```
chmod a+rwx directory-name -R
```