# Still getting a permison denied message on Laravel after configuring apache

Tags: laravel, centos7, laravel-5.6

i'm setting up a laravel project that i firstly developed locally, i'm trying to move it to my droplet and after sucefully configuring .env file and database among others, i still have problems with permissons or at least it seems to be the problem. I'm running Centos 7.2 (on a DigitalOcean droplet) and Laravel 5.6.

I'm getting the following message when i want to access any link other than the  index.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsFm7.png)

and this is my conf file:

https://pastebin.com/gfh5i93Z

I've already set permissons to correspondent folders with:

```
sudo chown -R apache: storage
sudo chmod -R 755 storage
```

and it stills giving me that error.

Any help will be very aprecciated, thanks!

Edit: It temporary works when i set Sellinux Enforcing to 0.

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo chmod -R 777 storage` 
and if doesn't help maybe running in whole project folder not just storage

775 permission for whole project is good I think , however you can find full answer with more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others).

Comment: I wolud consider that as a temporary fix, 777 permissons aren't a real option.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257975/permissions-issue-with-laravel-on-centos?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

This was my solution, it's a CentOS specific problem, thanks!