# laravel centOS 7 chmod 755/775 permission denied"could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied", only allows if I set to 777

Tags: linux, laravel, centos7

I have linux:

> Linux version 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64
>   (builder@kbuilder.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat
>   4.8.5-16) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Mar 7 19:03:37 UTC 2018

If I set the permission to 777 on storage, laravel works, but if I set it to 755 or 775  it says:

> "The stream or file
>   "/home/admin/domains/linkshift.eu/public_html/storage/logs/laravel-2018-11-08.log"
>   could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied"

I have tried searching for an answer, but nothing else worked, I have tried doing
[Permissions Issue with Laravel on CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257975/permissions-issue-with-laravel-on-centos)
but it still doesn't work

Edit: I also have direct admin installed

Comment: Stackoverflow is about helping programers.  This is more suited for super user community - https://superuser.com/

Comment: I am a programmer, I am just trying to host laravel on a dedicated server

Comment: But ok I will make a thread there, thank you for the link

Comment: I'm not saying, by any means, that you are not programmer.  I just think the question does not have any programming question.

Answer (score 1):

Look like the log file is generated using root user and you are running the laravel from a different user. Make sure the log file is written by same user. Or give permission to your user.

```
sudo chown -R laravel-user:laravel-user /path/to/your/laravel/root/directory
```

Run these commands after every deploy

```
chmod -R 775 storage/framework
chmod -R 775 storage/logs
chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache
```

Still If not working, It can maybe also because of SELinux.

Check selinux status on terminal:

```
sestatus
```

If status is enabled, write command for disable SElinux (not recommended)

```
setenforce Permissive
```

or you can do like below.

```
yum install policycoreutils-python -y # might not be necessary, try the below first

semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/path/to/your/laravel/root/directory/storage(/.*)?" # add a new httpd read write content to sellinux for the specific folder, -m for modify
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/path/to/your/laravel/root/directory/bootstrap/cache(/.*)?" # same as the above for b/cache

restorecon -Rv /var/www/html/ # this command is very important to, it's like a restart to apply the new rules
```

Selinux is intended to restrict access even to root users, so only the necessary stuff might be accessed, at least on a generalist overview, it's extra security, disabling it is not a good practise, there are many links to learn Selinux, but for this case it is not even required.

Comment: How can I do that? How do I check which user it is ran by?

Comment: setenforce: SELinux is disabled
and it still does not work, should I try to turn it on and then run the commands?

Comment: Run this `sudo chown -R laravel-user:laravel-user /path/to/your/laravel/root/directory`

Comment: Also I am running it on super user,  I have not created any users

Comment: Then try your luck with SElinux

Comment: also I should mention that I have direct admin installed

Comment: after doing what you said now I get " Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe"

Comment: chown to the web server's user. (which is probably www-data)
Try to run `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/your/laravel/root/directory`

Comment: Path do you mean like /home/admin/domains/shift.eu/public_html/     public html is the laravel folder

Comment: I did sudo chown -R apache:apache /home/admin/domains/linkshift.eu/public_html but nothing

Answer (score -2):

Could you show the result of

```
ls -l /home/admin/domains/linkshift.eu/public_html/storage/logs
```

and have you tried

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
composer dump-autoload -o
```

Comment: total 16
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache 14827 Nov  8 03:02 laravel-2018-11-08.log

Comment: I tried everything after doing chmod -R 775 storage, but still 
The stream or file "/home/admin/domains/linkshift.eu/public_html/storage/logs/laravel-2018-11-08.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: to confirm the name of user of your http server (which is assumed to be apache:apache here),  try delete laravel-2018-11-09.log, and set the permission to 777 on storage again, then trigger a execution which writes logs to let apache create a new laravel-2018-11-09.log, and then do ls -l again to see its ownership?

Comment: "total 0" is the output after I did what you said