# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied Laravel PDO Driver (credentials working via artisan migrate)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo

I'm having a lot of trouble with the PDO driver on this new installation

This is the error I get when trying to do any db operation triggered by laravel.

```
ext Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = ethan@gmail.com limit 1) in /var/www/html/mypath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:647
```

What's really strange here, is that PDO is enabled in php, and we're using the same credentials that php artisan migrate used to create the tables (so I know credentials, mysql socket are all working)

This is the PDO error from the stack

```
at PDO->__construct('mysql:unix_socket=/mnt/volume_sfo2_01/mysql_data/mysqld.sock;dbname=testdb1', 'dbuser1', 'mypassword', array(0, 2, 0, false, false))
in Connector.php line 68
```

Note that I did move the datadirectory of mysql and thus the change for the socket.  This config works running the migrate, so what am I missing to get it working with the laravel PDO driver?

On ubuntu server 16 as well.
Nginx + php7.1
apparmor has been disabled additional just for this testing.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you see if "use PDO;" helps, also, are you using homestead or Xampp?

Comment: Make sure that your config isn’t cached. Run php artisan config:clear from your console

Answer (score 19):

I had similar issue on Laravel/Lumen 5.5 / CentOS7 / php71 / mariaDB

using the 'setenforce to test' strategy outlined in the solution here, [Permissions Issue with Laravel on CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257975/permissions-issue-with-laravel-on-centos) you might want to test for the influence of SElinux.

I was connecting via port 3306 and was able to resolve with insight from this problem report (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1245295) that lead me to

```
sudo setsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

to make this change permenant you need to add -P switch

`sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1`

Comment: Thanks! This is working on CentOS 7 with Laravel 5.6 for me.

Comment: I was getting the same error codes when my PHP code was trying to access a MySQL database over the network when accessed from the browser (not using Laravel or any framework, just a vanilla PHP site). When running a PHP script from the command line, it worked fine though. Turns out, it was this SE Linux `httpd_can_network_connect_db` variable that was the culprit. Setting it to 1 fixed everything! Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, you save me.

Comment: in 2023 - this sorted my problem instantly on centos 9 stream --- Thanks!