# Running chrome headless on Laravel Process

Tags: laravel, google-chrome

I'm trying to take a screenshot of a website using laravel and headless chrome.
Google Chrome was installed successfully on my Centos 7 server. 
I'm doing test using this shell command and it was successful.

```
    google-chrome --headless --screenshot --window-size=1350,768 --hide-scrollbars https://google.com
```

In Laravel 6.6.0, I'm using Symfony Process to run the command. Below is the code.

```
    $process = new Process("google-chrome --headless --screenshot --window-size=1350,768 --hide-scrollbars https://google.com");
    $process->setTimeout(8000);
    $process->setWorkingDirectory(storage_path('app/public/'));
    $process->run();
```

However, it gives below error. I don't know what error it is.

I tried to verify the server permission by replacing with this code. It was successful.

```
    $process = new Process('cat > test2.txt');
    $process->setWorkingDirectory(storage_path('app/public'));
    $process->run();
```

Also tried oh plain php with this code

```
<?php

   shell_exec('google-chrome --headless --screenshot --window-size=1350,768 --hide-scrollbars --no-sandbox https://google.com'); //failed

   shell_exec('cat > test.txt'); //success

?>
```

Am I missing something?

Below is Laravel Error

```
Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessSignaledException
The process has been signaled with signal "4".

Symfony\Component\Process\Process::wait  :426
vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:426
```

.

```
$this->callback = $this->buildCallback($callback);

    }



    do {

        $this->checkTimeout();

        $running = '\\' === \DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ? $this->isRunning() : $this->processPipes->areOpen();

        $this->readPipes($running, '\\' !== \DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR || !$running);

    } while ($running);



    while ($this->isRunning()) {

        $this->checkTimeout();

        usleep(1000);

    }



    if ($this->processInformation['signaled'] && $this->processInformation['termsig'] !== $this->latestSignal) {

        throw new ProcessSignaledException($this);

    }



    return $this->exitcode;

}
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message, including stacktrace, you are getting?

Comment: Jerodev, edited the question with error message.

Comment: Laravel 5.6 or 6.0? The version 6.6.0 doesn't exist.

Comment: thmspl, it's the latest one, 6.6.0. Got it from artisan --version

Answer (score 0):

Signal 4 is related to Permission issue, make your www-data user a sudoer on the command "google-chrome" and change your command to `sudo google-chrome --head ...`

Also, your code

```php
$url = "https://google.com";
$name = Str::slug($url, '-');
```

turns `https://google.com` into `httpsgooglecom`. I think your issue is with the variable `$name` being not a valid url.

Use `$url`:

```php
$process = new Process("sudo google-chrome --headless --screenshot --window-size=1350,768 --hide-scrollbars --virtual-time-budget=250005" .$url);
```

Comment: same error. I even put the url directly in the command without the variable.
Fyi, I have posted full stack trace in the question.

Comment: @lucaditrimma Edited the answer and provided a temporary solution with sudo

Comment: yes you are right. It's SELinux permission issue but sudo didn't work either. I have to turn off the SELinux. However, this suggestion didn't work for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257975/permissions-issue-with-laravel-on-centos

Answer (score 0):

I found out SELinux that causing the problem.
After turning it off, the code successfully do the screenshot and write to that folder.
I found this solution on how to do it with SELinux enabled but it not worked for me right now. Maybe it solves others.

[Permissions Issue with Laravel on CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257975/permissions-issue-with-laravel-on-centos)