# PHP write permission denied

Tags: php, apache, centos, centos7

I'm running a server on CentOS 7.
User `apache` | Group apache has `775` permissions on `/var/www/html`
When I execute a PHP file that wants to create a new file in `root dir (/var/www/html/)` I get the following error
`Warning: file_put_contents(file.bin): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/file.php`

PHP code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
$file = 'file.bin';
$content = "Content";
file_put_contents($file, $content);
?>
```

I will update the question with more data but since I'm new I don't know too many things about debugging server errors.

What I tried:

- For executing scripts (php..) I saw the user to be apache so I gave 'apache' ownership on /var/www/html/
- tried `777` on `./html` (and reversed action after it didn't work to 755)
- Also  tried `cd /var/www/html` `chmod -R 775 .` (from comments)

Comment: You need to write to a directory that the user running the webserver has write permission to.

Comment: `cd /var/www/html` `chmod -R 775 .`

Comment: @medilies I tried that already and setting the owner of HTML as apache (user which executes PHP files (checked that by executing a command in PHP forgot what it was)

Comment: @Barmar the thing is I can set 777 everywhere but it still can't do it

Comment: Show a [mcve], it might be something related to your code?

Comment: Wait, what is the exact code?  Did you `file_put_contents(/var/www/html/file.php)` ?  Remember that from PHP's perspective, `/` is already under `/var/www/html`.  So it should be `file_put_contents(/file.php)`.  Note, not real code, just to show you that you should not use absolute patch from the system's `/`.

Comment: @Nic3500 I added my code to the question.  I tried `file_put_contents("/var/www/html/file.bin", "smth");` and relative path `file_put_contents("file.bin", "smth")` both produced the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a high degree of probability, the issue is with `selinux`.
if you turning off `selinux` with the command (from root) :

```
setenforce 0
```

and everything will work, you need to turning on `selinux` with the command (from root):

```
setenforce 1
```

and run the command:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /your/path
```

Everything must work. If this method does not help, I advise you to read answers  [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257975/permissions-issue-with-laravel-on-centos). There is an answer with a more flexible `selinux`  settings (with using `sudo semanage fcontext`).

Comment: Thank you, `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html` worked