# Upload files when using homestead

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, homestead

I'm moving my project to homestead and I got strange behavior when it comes to uploading files. Previously when working no on homestead it worked fine.

Code which is responsible for uploading files:

```
$path = $request->file('result')->store('results');
$fileContent = Storage::get($path);
```

So it should just store a file under results folder.

What actually happens:

1. For some reason the permissions on the results folder become 755 even though I set them to 777 before
2. I got an error when uploading file: fopen(/home/vagrant/Sites/pft/api/storage/app/results/9g1tx5bDuMU2XBtfhXqDrQ9VT1m6dZJJa84Sqgyx.txt): failed to open stream: Protocol error

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055056/laravel-log-could-not-be-opened-failed-to-open-stream

Comment: Actually I couldn't even change folder owner to www-data: sudo chown -R yourusername:www-data storage didn't change it, I got vagrant/vagrant owner

Comment: Oops, actually I should set permissions from my mac, not homestead