# The stream or file could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, centos, centos7

The stream or file "/var/www/maheshiya.com/public_html/storage/logs/laravel-2019-02-06.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

[image]

How to fix this eror? Centos 7

Comment: Please don't post images of [code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) or [exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)

Comment: Why do you share log files publicly? Seemes your application or web server does not have write access to that file.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055056/laravel-log-could-not-be-opened-failed-to-open-stream

Comment: You have to change owner to apache user `www-data`. so it can perform the task. You can solve this simply running this command  `chown -R www-data:www-data storage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper solution is not to give every user on a server access to your storage directory or logs.

The proper solutions are either:

1. Don't run artisan commands as other users so the log files aren't created/owned by another user.  Run chown on the log files so the proper user owns it to correct this.

   chown -R user storage/logs

Or

2. If you have some need for other users to run artisan commands,  use a setgid bit and umask on the log directory so the group is constant and anyone a part of the group can write to the files in the directory. (More advanced)

Comment: Its Not work here, Im using Root user

Comment: Your web server and application should never be run as root.