# Laravel - Failed to open stream

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, frameworks

I installed Laravel on my remote server, but i get this error:

```
file_put_contents(/www/htdocs/user-id/domain.com/app/storage/meta/services.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I changed permissions

```
app/storage
```

to

```
777
```

and i followed instructions from:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020513/laravel-4-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied/22192814#22192814
```

But error stayed.

Anybody could help me with this?

Greetings and thanks!

Comment: Just to be sure, have you changed the permissions *recursively*?

Comment: nope, changing permissions from 'app/storage' recursively could be an security issue, so i didnt do that, is there any other solution?

Comment: How would that be a security issue? There's nothing in there you should be worried about...

Comment: mhm ok and how to change it quickly recursively? dont wanna do every single file/directory :/

Comment: Use the `-R` option: `chmod -R 777 app/storage`

Comment: ok thanks i will try with putty