# Deploying Laravel 5.2 unusual permission error

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, deployment, permissions

I am trying to load my project on the live server.

these are the specs

PHP version 5.6
Server : Windows

I have loaded all the files and chmod 777

Storage 
Vendor
bootstrap/cache

but it keeps giving me the following streaming error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with
>   message 'The stream or file
>   "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\websites\mysite\storage/logs/laravel.log" could
>   not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\websites\mysite\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler.php:87
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\websites\mysite\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37):
>   Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array) #1
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\websites\mysite\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\Logger.php(336):
>   Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array) #2
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\websites\mysite\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\Logger.php(615):
>   Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(UnexpectedValueException),
>   Array) #3
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\websites\mysite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Log\Writer.php(202):
>   Monolog\Logger->error(Object(UnexpectedValueExc
>   in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\websites\mysite\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler.php on
>   line 87
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with
>   message 'The stream or file
>   "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\websites\mysite\storage/logs/laravel.log" could
>   not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\websites\mysite\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler.php:87
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\websites\mysite\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37):
>   Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array) #1
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\websites\mysite\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\Logger.php(336):
>   Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array) #2
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\websites\mysite\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\Logger.php(615):
>   Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400,
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException), Array)> 
>    3 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\websites\mysite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Log\Writer.php(202):
>   Monolog\Logger->er
>   in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\websites\mysite\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler.php on
>   line 87

Comment: cross check 777 applied or not in log folder

Comment: delete the log files

Comment: cross checked but no solution.

deleted the logfiles but not working at all

Comment: Refer : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020513/laravel-4-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set permissions correctly. You're on Windows, so [read this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754344.aspx) or [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-File-Permissions-on-Windows-7). `storage` folder **with all subfolders and files** should be accessible to r&w.

Comment: done but same error can't actually figures this out.

Comment: Look at `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\websites\mysite\storage/logs/laravel.log` file permissions. Probably you do not set permissions correctly, for example you may change permissions for folder, but not files in it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to allow writing for logs dir `chmod -R 777 storage/logs`

Comment: Then right click on folder <server root>/storage/logs and set permissions to allow write access

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, turns out the server didnt create the file with the correct **owner**, even though permissions were set correctly. Hope this helps someone!

I deleted that particular log (im using daily logs) and it worked again.

Answer (score -1):

Delete laravel.log file inside logs folder.
It worked for me.