# Laravel in aws - failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I am facing this issue in AWS Server,

> The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not
> be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

And I give permission to "777",Now

```
sudo chmod -R 755 storage/

sudo chmod -R 777 storage/
```

> ErrorException
> file_put_contents(/var/www/html/storage/framework/sessions/UMNbxoQBZjaUuZK7j4IHfRp3fWJF8pd688gnWX4o):
> failed to open stream: Permission denied

I receive this error Please help me to fix.

Comment: are u using cent os .? and please mention your `OS`

Comment: Yes I am using CentOS 7.8.

Comment: try this `sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t storage`

Comment: Not working to me,My app url :subdomain.domain.com ,Any settings need for subdomian?

Comment: it not related to domain it just a permission issue

Answer (score 0):

as u r using **CentOS 7.8**

> try `sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t storage` to give full permission to `storage`

Answer (score 0):

This question is really trending when it comes to Laravel. The best suggestion I can give is change read/write/exec permissions of your storage folder like:

```
sudo chmod -Rf 755 storage
```

> The -f is to make command run on subfiles and subdirectories all
> through

And make sure apache and user has access/ownership to storage folder like:

```
sudo chown -Rf username:apache storage
```

Importantly: Always avoid using 777 as it gives permission to anyone to have access to your files and folder outside your usergroup.

Selah!

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020513/laravel-4-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied?rq=1 for more info